# EC2 | SSH works but GIT does not

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, permissions, permission-denied

I just set up an EC2 server and I am trying to push local files from my machine to the server with git.

**On the server, I initialized a git repo inside of `/home/ec2-user/`:**

```
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare
```

**On the client I use the following command:**

`git fetch origin master`

**Which results in the error:**

```
Permission denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

**This is what my local repo's config file looks like: (url IP changed for question)**

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ec2-user@ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:project.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

**This command WORKS: (I am able to ssh in)**

`ssh ec2-user@ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Because the command above works, I would think that my PEM key is not the issue, seeing how it allows me to ssh into the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, I would start testing with the full repository path:

```
git remote set-url origin ec2-user@ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/project.git
```

That would ensure that Git is looking at the folder you are trying to reach.

The OP mentions in the chat using

```
ssh -i "ec2-ohio.pem" ec2-user@ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

That means the private key used is not the default `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa`

For Git to use it, it needs to refer to said key through the URL, and `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config`

First, in the config file, declare an ec2 entry (you can call it any name you want, I use one which reminds me of the remote server target)

```
Host ec2
    Hostname ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    User ec2-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ec2-ohio.pem
```

Then change the remote URL to use that entry (and its associated private key)

```
git remote set-url origin ec2:/home/ec2-user/project.git
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error with that URL set in my config. Any other ideas to test?

Comment: The PEM that I use for SSH is the same that should be used with git I assume, correct?

Comment: @Wyatt Assuming Linux, can you test `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv" git ls-remote origin`. Or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv" git ls-remote  ec2-user@ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/project.git`

Comment: I'm on windows. My server runs Ubuntu

Comment: @Wyatt Then `set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -Tv"`. Followed by, as a separate command: `git ls-remote ec2-user@ec2-22-222-22-222.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ec2-user/project.git `

Comment: @Wyatt I meant the all output would help. Is your private key the default `%USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa`? Is it passphrase protected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217230/discussion-between-vonc-and-wyatt).