# which directory should ssh keys be put for gitbash to work correctly

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

I recently formatted my laptop. I am on a Windows 10 machine. I have had taken ssh keys backup long time back. The keys were created on Linux virtual machine.
which directory should ssh keys be put for gitbash to work correctly.
In the new laptop I downloaded my previous ssh keys from google drive,
the keys are in following location

```
C:\Users\koidera\arbit_user\downloaded software\git\git keys
```

There are two keys one is kiotie32_rsa.pub and another is

```
C:\Users\koidera\arbit_user\downloaded software\git\git keys\private key
```

kiotie32_rsa

Now I installed gitbash.

```
C:\Users\koidera\arbit_user\installation\Git
```

So now I want to know where should I place the private key and public key to make them work with my account. I have not configured the username and password section which was previously configured.
I have forgotten all the things how I did it that time. But assuming I google and do that initial configuration for username password of that account. I am not able to understand where should I put my ssh keys to work in this Windows 10 environment.

I have checked many folders in Gitbash installation directory
I found one

```
C:\Users\koidera\arbit_user\installation\Git\etc\ssh
```

But this does not seem to be correct location to me. (I may be wrong).
I want to configure multiple github accounts for multiple projects.
So I just wanted to know where should I put my keys both public and private.
I don't want to do a global git configuration just for specific project specific username and key based authentication.

For a different folder in my windows OS a different username in same laptop is what I want to achieve and all this based on ssh keys.
Since this is a fresh Windows installation so I want to do every thing fresh.

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use on windows the location is usually `C:\users\<username>\.ssh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to put those keys in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`

But, second, assuming they are not passphrase-protected, you also need to declare them in a `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\config file` ([as I did recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724407/6309))

```
Host target
  Hostname server.target.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private_key
```

(replace '`target`' by a more evocative name, and `server.target.com` and `git` by the actual server name and remote User account)

Then use for remote URL that config entry, thereby referencing the right private key:

```
git clone target:<me>/<myRepo>
```